# Rails Active Record Query Results

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

following a rails 3 tutorial, I have a scope defined to limit the orders column and a helper method to sum the results
Scope

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :cart_id, :product_id, :cart, :product, :quantity

belongs_to :order
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :cart

scope :order, -> {where("order != nil")}
end
```

Helper

```
 module StoreHelper

  def total_product_sold (product)    
 product.line_items.total_product.sum("quantity")
end
```

problem is when i call total_product_sold from my view it sums all data in orders column as opposed to only the ones where the order number is !=nil.

I also tried defining a class method as opposed to scope

```
 def self.total_product
 where(order !=nil)
 end
```

but this gives me the same exact result. what am i doing wrong? how do i get it to add only the items whose order column are not nil?

Comment: Please indent your code appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't find records that are not NULL using `!= nil`.  You need to use the SQL syntax `IS NOT NULL`:

```
scope :order, -> { where("line_items.order_id IS NOT NULL") }
```

or:

```
def self.total_product
  where("line_items.order_id IS NOT NULL")
end
```

Alternatively, you can join the `:order` association which effectively does the filtering for you.  However, there is a performance penalty for this:

```
def total_product_sold (product)     
  product.line_items.joins(:order).sum("quantity")
end
```

Comment: sweet thanks bro! btw it didnt work with scope for some odd reason but it worked perfectly with the class method.